# "a" tag with target="_blank" in ASP.NET Core MVC not working

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to add a link in our ASP.NET Core MVC web site to an external website and I want to open it in a new tab.

```
<a href="https://www.mozilla.org" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Update browser</a>
```

Unfortunately, with `target="_blank"`, nothing happens when I click on it.

Tested in Chrome, Edge, Firefox.

Without the `_blank` target, it correctly opens in the same tab.

In a newly created ASP.NET Core MVC app, the `_blank` target works fine.

Please, does anyone have an idea what could be blocking this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"nothing happens when I click on it."_ - does anything appear in your browser console? do you have any scripts in the page that could be hijacking things? browser settings, etc?

Comment: _"In a newly created ASP.NET Core MVC app, the _blank target works fine. Please, does anyone have an idea what could be blocking this?"_ - the difference is somewhere between the newly created app and all the customizations you did.

Comment: Nothing in the browser console @Dai

Comment: I know that the difference is somewhere in the newly created app and the customisations in the app @CodeCaster... problem is that the app development is already in a pretty far development stage. It is in production for an year and a half and many developers already contributed to it.

Comment: ...and this happens in **all browsers**? If so, then that definitely sounds like you've got some JS breaking your page.

Comment: Yeah but it can be about anything. Someone could have overridden the anchor tag helper, there can be JavaScript that's listening to click events, and everything in between.

Comment: ah, found something extra in one of the browsers console log:
 
"Blocked opening xxxx was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set."

Interesting, but I'm not in a frame...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the console message was not perfectly clear but I found it.

We have CSP rules, and I had to add 'allow-popups' to allow blank target...

Only a day and a half to find it...